# How to execute multiple targets with different options in grunt-contrib-jshint

Tags: gruntjs, jshint, grunt-contrib-jshint

Goal: to flex the execution of jshint to output results to the console (if in development) or to a file (if being released/in Jenkins).

Is it possible? I can add individual targets to my jshint settings, but all of my options are the same except for the reporter details.  So it'd be nice to not duplicate those.  I need to do the concatenation from "all" and use all of the global options and the specific options from the target that is called.  How?

jshint.js:

```
module.exports = {
    options: {
        node: true,
        browser: true,
        blah: blah...
    },
    all: [
        'Gruntfile.js',
        '<%= yeoman.app %>/modules/**/*.js',
        '<%= yeoman.app %>/*.js'
    ],
    dev: {
        options: {
            reporter: 'checkstyle'
        }
    }
    release: {
        options: {
            reporter: 'checkstyle',
            reporterOutput: 'myfile.xml'
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going the variable route but using that for the files source and then overriding the necessary options in the targets.

```
var files = [
    'Gruntfile.js',
    '<%= yeoman.app %>/modules/**/*.js',
    '<%= yeoman.app %>/*.js'
];

module.exports = {
    options: {
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish'),
        node: true, ...
    },
    dev: {
        src: files
    },
    release: {
        src: files,
        options: {
            reporter: 'checkstyle',
            reporterOutput: 'myfile.xml',
            reporterOutputRelative: false
        }
    }
}
```

Based on other things I had read, I didn't think the default options would work in the targets and allow overriding, and I also had encountered problems with the files, but this solved everything.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you, its just a sample you can improve the code.

**install : grunt-contrib-jshint**

Gruntfile.js

```
//Jshint ===============================    
            var jshint;
            config.jshint = jshint ={};


            jshint.dist = {
                options: {jshintrc: ".jshintrc"},
                files: {all: ["lib/main.js","lib/test.js"]}
            };

            jshint.dev = {
                options: {jshintrc: ".jshintrc.dev"},
                files: {all: ["lib/main.js","lib/test.js"]}
            };
```

**.jshintrc**

```
{
        "strict":true,
        "laxcomma":true,
        "sub":true
}
```

**.jshintrc.dev**

```
{
        "strict":true,
        "laxcomma":true,
        "sub":true,
        "debug":true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a subset of options that will be the same between two targets, you can create a variable for the object and assign its value to both target's `option` key:

```
var reporterOptions = {
        foo: 'red',
        bar: 'green',
        baz: 'blue'
    };

    module.exports = {
        options: {
            node: true,
            browser: true,
            blah: blah...
        },
        all: [
            'Gruntfile.js',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/modules/**/*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/*.js'
        ],
        dev: {
            options: reporterOptions
        }
        release: {
            options: reporterOptions
        }
    };
```

If you want to maintain your option values in one place, but want to selectively decide which options are applied to which targets, you can reference the values stored in the variable using dot notation.

```
var reporterOptions = {
    foo: 'red',
    bar: 'green',
    baz: 'blue'
};

module.exports = {
    options: {
        node: true,
        browser: true,
        blah: blah...
    },
    all: [
        'Gruntfile.js',
        '<%= yeoman.app %>/modules/**/*.js',
        '<%= yeoman.app %>/*.js'
    ],
    dev: {
        options: {
          foo: reporterOptions.foo
          bar: reporterOptions.bar
        }
    }
    release: {
        options: {
          foo: reporterOptions.foo
          baz: reporterOptions.baz
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Ah, interesting.  How do I then handle options that are unique between release and dev?

Comment: Updated answer based on your comment.  You'd store all options you want to share amongst targets in a variable, and then when defining the values for the specific target's options, reference the values stored in the variable using dot notation

Comment: IMO, it's probably overkill for the number of properties you might share between the various targets, but to each their own